# XNA 2D Camera Not Moving

Tags: matrix, xna, camera

I am creating a game engine and a test game, and I am currently working on cameras (using Matrix transforms). However, I am running into the strangest problem. I have a variable called CameraPosition (Vector2) that sets the position of the camera. The camera will move fine when I move the camera by doing something like
    `CameraPosition += new Vector2(0, 4);`
(the camera will move up and all objects will appear to move down). However, when I do this:
    `CameraPosition = ship.Position;`
nothing happens: the camera stays in the exact same spot, even though the ships position is changing. I've checked, and the matrix is changing as well, but it's not affecting the drawing.

PS: The code I'm using to calculate the matrix is this:
    `CameraMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(new Vector3(CameraPosition, 0));`

and the code I'm using to draw is this:
    `spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null, null, CameraMatrix);
    //draw stuff here...
    spriteBatch.End();`

If anyone has any ideas on what's going on/needs to see more of the code, feel free to ask/tell!

EDIT: Rotation and scaling/zooming work fine: it's just the translations that are messing up.

Comment: If both the matrix and `ship.Position` are changing, it would suggest your problems are coming from not correctly referencing `CameraPosition` during your drawing. However, you said adding to the `CameraPosition` `Vector2` with a `+=` operation does actually move objects around. Unless you've come across a bug, it sounds like you haven't described your issue well enough!

Comment: The thing is @Joe, though, the only use for CameraPosition is for making the matrix. Also, I did forget to say that CameraPosition is also changing.

Comment: Try using `ship.Position` in your matrix assignment, does that generate the results you are wanting? I don't mean this is a solution, this is only a means to try find out what's wrong!

Comment: Nope: exact same result.

Comment: Unfortunately I've not used this method for a camera before! When I use a `Camera` I use it's `X` and `Y` coordinates directly in determining draw coordinates. i.e `Vector2 drawPos = obj.Pos - camera.Pos;`

Comment: The main reason I used matrices is that it allows zoom and rotation quite easily. Oh, by the way, those work fine as well.